# Function become buggy by putting brackets around IF statment and FOR loop

Tags: javascript

The following code works fine. But  if i put brackets around IF and FOR. 
Then it does not works,

```js
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == undefined)
    exponent = 2;
  result = 1;
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
    result *= base;
  return result;
}
console.log(power(4, 3)); //64
console.log(power(4)) //16
```

Comment: IF statement and For loop statement both cannot be considered as an expression. That is why you are seeing error

Comment: What did you change? What error did you get?

Comment: function power(base,exponent){
  if(exponent == undefined){
  exponent = 2;
  result =1;
 }
  for(var count = 0; count<exponent;count++){
  result *=  base;
  return result;
 }
 }
console.log(power(4,3));
console.log(power(4))
//error result is not defined

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run the code with brackets. Maybe you had `result = 1` or `return result` within the brackets by accident?

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == undefined) {
    exponent = 2;
  }

  result = 1;

  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++) {
    result *= base;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(power(4, 3)); // 64
console.log(power(4)) // 16
```

Comment: Yeh, you right. result  was inside the bracketes. It works now. 
Thanks

Comment: Anytime M Sohaib Khan!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use bracket is compiled like that

```
if(i==0)
   res=0;
  res=4;
```

equal to

```
if(i==0){
   res=0;
}
res=4;
```

Only the **first line** after the test/loop is considered in the test/loop that's why you have differences between your tests

Add bracket like that to obtain the same result :

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == undefined){
    exponent = 2;
  }
  result = 1;
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
  {
    result *= base;
  }
  return result;
}
```